# Read one line till end of the line then pick next and so on in text file use shell script

Tags: shell

i am working on debian system for hardening. I have one text file with several lines. Each line ends with some tabs and next line begins from new line. I want to read every line till end also till end of the file. But stuck at while loop it loops file at once and also lines. i want to stop loop after every line so that i can process that single line an go to next line after getting that line's result.

sample compliance file which i want to process

```
07:45:55 PM Compliance status:Yes 2.1 /tmp partition
07:45:55 PM Compliance status:No  2.5 /var partition
07:45:55 PM Compliance status:No  2.7 /var/log partition
07:45:55 PM Compliance status:Yes 2.9 /home partition
07:45:55 PM Compliance status:Yes 3.1 /boot/grub/grub.cfg
07:45:55 PM Compliance status:No  3.2  /boot/grub/grub.cfg
07:45:55 PM Compliance status:Yes 3.4  etc/shadow
```

sample code:

```
count = 1
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    #echo "Text read from file $count: $line"

    some_var=`cut -f4 -d" " <<< $line | cut -d":" -f2` #cuts Yes/No from every line of compliance file

    if [ "$some_var" == "No" ]
    then
        echo "Yes apply remedy"
    else
        echo "No need to apply remedy"
    fi
    count=$((count+1)) 
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried so we might be able to help.

Comment: What result are you getting, and what result do you expect?

Comment: i want to apply remedy according to the compliance status mentioned above Yes/No. i am able to read file using while loop as i am trying to stop while loop after one line and process that line and should go to second line and so on till end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read is pretty much designed to do all the work for you:

```
while read time ampm comp status ver partition; do
  echo at $time, $partition had status $comp $status
done < input-file
```

It will enter the loop for each line of input, splitting the line on the first character of IFS into the named variables. All you need to do is use the variables.

Comment: If I may add something. If OP want to test the status : if [[ ${status#*:} == "No" ]] ....

Comment: can u tell me how to do it with IFS? @william Pursell

Comment: The best way to use IFS is to simply never change IFS.  If you have changed it, then write `while IFS=' ' read ....`.  Just give the variable names as arguments to `read`, and it will assign the fields for you.

Comment: The reason it's setup like this is so that you can (for example) parse colon separated files with syntax like `while IFS=: read acct passwd uid gid cmt home shell; do ... done < /etc/passwd`.  Since your file is white space delimited, you can (usually) just drop the IFS assignment and write `while read ...`